# Terminal Command to show only the first level files with ls -R

Tags: terminal, filesystems, zsh, ls

I want to have a clear picture of my files in my project folder. But I don't want to see the content of the subfolders. I am doing `ls -R` in order to get the files in a fashionable manner but it displays all file. For example, I have the node modules inside each Client folder `see below`. Here is my file system:

```
WebstormProjects
|--Porject1
|   |--Client
|   |  |--node_modules
|   |  |--etc...
|   |--Server
|--Project2
|   |--Client
|   |--Server
```

The same for the second file. When I hit `ls -R` it shows me not only the first level files that I want to see Client Server or something else, but Everything inside them too, 8 Levels down and stuff.

I even tried `ls -R -1`, but the only thing that  it does is put them in the same column. `-maxdepth -1`, `-depth 1` doesn't work.

**What is the correct way to do it with `ls`? I do not want to use find or something else. I want a command to display my current directory in a somewhat structured way, like the one above, `a filesystem of sorts` but in the terminal.**

If you know any other commands please add them `Using Linux Ubuntu 18.04, with zsh`. Thanks!!

Comment: If you want to see just the content of your current directory, do one of `ls` or `ls -A`. If you want to see the whole directory tree, but only the directories, not the files they contain, use `find . -type d`.

Comment: Note also that some Linux distribution also contain a utility called `tree` which displays the directory tree in an intended way.

Comment: Thank you. I went with the tree solution for now. I am not happy about it truth be told. Probably when I have time I should create a terminal app to suit my needs as I want to have specific display options that those solutions don't offer...